# How to handle updates to a REST resource when using hypermedia links

Tags: rest, hateoas

I'm working a REST-ful API in which resources which are fairly interrelated.  Resources reference each other, and these references may be created or deleted.  I'm a little uncertain how to support associating resources together when they reference each other using hyperlinks.

A simple example follows with two resources, A and B.

> ```
> Resource A:
>   name: integer
>   list_b: [list of resource B]
>
> Resource B:
>   id: integer
>   description: String
> ```

Now, A does not include B in its document, but rather links to it.  When using hypermedia, it might look something like this:

> ```
> Resource A:
> {
>     id: 1,
>     list_b: [
>         { id: 1, href: "https://server/api/b/1" },
>         { id: 2, href: "https://server/api/b/2" }
>     ]
> }
> ```

If a user wants to add or delete one of the B references in A's list, how do they do so, taking into account the presence of the hyperlink?  I want the user to be able to update the entire A resource in one PUT operation, but nothing in the output indicates which value for B is required.  It make sense to me for the user to perform PUT with content like this:

> ```
> Resource A:
> {
>     id: 1,
>     list_b: [
>         { id: 1, href: "https://server/api/b/1" },
>         { id: 2, href: "https://server/api/b/2" },
>         { id: 3 },
>     ]
> }
> ```

and receive the updated resource (in the response) like this:

> ```
> Resource A:
> {
>     id: 1,
>     list_b: [
>         { id: 1, href: "https://server/api/b/1" },
>         { id: 2, href: "https://server/api/b/2" },
>         { id: 3, href: "https://server/api/b/3" }
>     ]
> }
> ```

My concern is that the user won't necessarily know what to include in the resource when updating resource A's `list_b`.

When dealing with hyperlinks from one resource to another, how should creates and updates work?  Should clients be allowed to update part of the link (the `id`), or should they be required to update both parts of the link?

**Note:** I know another approach might be exposing a sub-url for resource A.  It could expose `list_b` as a resource which is operable via HTTP (allowing clients to use POST, PUT, and DELETE on the list resource itself).  But this seems less reasonable when A contains multiple references to other resource types.  Each field which references another would potentially require a sub-url, which, if there are 10+ fields, is unwieldy, and requires multiple HTTP requests to update the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HATEOAS connects resources together in a RESTful interface, and it's not clear here whether or not the subsidiary objects you're describing really make sense as independent resources.  The "AS" part of HATEOAS reminds us of the role that Web pages play as "resources" in a Web application.  Each Web page is really an interactive representation of application state (the "application" in this case being a classical, multiple-page Web application), and the hyperlinks to other resources provide the user with transitions to other application states.

A RESTful Web API, having JavaScript code rather than human beings as its client, is naturally data-access-oriented, so few if any of its resources take the form of "application state," *per se*.  In a tradition Web application, you can draw a state transition diagram and clearly see the connections among states, and thus among resources.  In a RESTful API, the boundaries among passive data resources are motivated more by the efficiencies of client/server interactions and other subtle forces.

So do your subsidiary objects ("B") here really need to be represent as first-class resources?  Are there instances where the front end will enumerate or otherwise access them independent of the aggregates in which they participate ("A")?

If the answer is "no," then they obviously shouldn't be represented hyptertextually in the "A" structure.  I presume that the answer is "yes," however, and that you also have good reason to offer all of the other subsidiary objects to which you refer as independent resources.  In this case, there's some amount of interface work in the form of routes and controllers that is necessary to support all of those resources no matter what, because your application is presumably providing a means to manipulate them each on their own, or at least query them (through hyperlinks such as those in your example).

This being the case, a POST to the path representing your collection of "B" objects (e.g., "server/api/b") can return a URL in the response's "location" header value as POSTs that create new resources are supposed to do.  When your user interactively adds a new "B" to a list belonging to an "A" on your Web page, your front end can first POST the new "B," getting its URL back through the location header on success.  It can then incorporate that link into the list representation inside its "A" object before PUTting the updated "A."

The ID value is a bit of a wrinkle, as you'll be tempted to break the encapsulation of the back end by extracting the ID value from the text of the URL.  True HATEOAS zealots make their RESTful APIs produce obfuscated, hashed or otherwise unintelligible URLs specifically to frustrate such encapsulation-breaking on the part of clients.  Better that the POST of the new "B" object returns a complete representation of the new "B" object, including its ID, in its response body, so that the client can reconstitute the full object and extract the ID from it, thus narrowing the coupling to the resource itself and not the details of the RESTful interface through which it is obtained.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. You are correct in that the resources I'm working with are much more complex and do indeed have their own use-model as first-class resources (my example is, admittedly, very simple).  All resource creation in this API does indeed return URLs in the location header, so it sounds like you're saying that the list_b could be limited to containing only URLs (no IDs), which the client should have anyway.  If a user wanted to add an existing B resource to this list, they would use the URL.  Is that a fair interpretation?

Comment: Yes, without knowing further details, I'd say that's a fair interpretation.

Comment: Thanks again.  So would you advocate for all resource references in an entity body (I know, this is a sweeping generalization), to be just a URL?

Comment: If your client code has no needs beyond fetching the resources in question, then this is the simplest arrangement, but alternatives can work too if your client's needs are more complex.  Embedding whole representations, for example, may be desirable to avoid client/server overhead, and the back end can do the translation necessary to ignore embedded resource representations on a PUT.  I'm far from a HATEOAS bigot myself, by the way:  http://compulsoryblog.com/2012/02/14/hypermedia-constraint-considered-harmful-episode-1-the-phantom-menace/

Comment: Interesting post -- thanks.  The API does in deed have some resources which embed others as lesser citizens, but the situation in the post does keep arising.

Comment: Archival link for link in Jollymorphic's comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20141020072742/http://compulsoryblog.com/2012/02/14/hypermedia-constraint-considered-harmful-episode-1-the-phantom-menace/

Answer (score 1):

You should also look at the [`LINK` method](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-snell-link-method-02):

```
LINK /ResourceA/1 HTTP/1.1
Link: <http://example.com/ResourceB/3>; rel="list_b"
...

204 Yeah Fine, Whatever
```

This tells /ResourceA/1 to link to /ResourceB/3 using the relationship "list_b".

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link!  I'm trying to adhere to the vanilla HTTP specification as much as possible, and the framework I'm using doesn't support the LINK method.  Still an interesting idea though.

Comment: What framework is that? Really, a framework that doesn't support arbitrary method names is not forward-compatible. Does it support [the `PATCH` method](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789), which is now standardised, for example?

Comment: I'm using Java's Jersey framework in tandem with Tomcat servlets for facilitating requests.  It's possible they have a way to specify arbitrary method names, but I'm sticking with vanilla HTTP for maximum supportability across clients.

Comment: The two, vanilla HTTP (by which I assume you mean the methods supported by HTML forms, GET and POST), and 'full HTTP' as defined by the IETF, don't have to be exclusive. My web app supports DELETE as well as POST with a HTTP_Method_Override=DELETE hidden form field for clients that are retarded. The POST handler simply passes the request off to the DELETE handler if it sees that field. You can do the same (assuming Jersey+Tomcat support it). You get maximum client support + "good" clients can use the more specific methods where appropriate.